# Save coordinates of image drawn on canvas in a variable/object-HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to get the coordinates of the last drawn shape so as to be able to apply transformations such as scaling, rotating etc. to it. This is the part of the code i used to draw the shape:

```
function drawPolygon(position, sides, angle) {
var coordinates = [],
    radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((dragStartLocation.x - position.x), 2) + Math.pow((dragStartLocation.y - position.y), 2)),
    index = 0;

for (index = 0; index < sides; index++) {
    coordinates.push({x: dragStartLocation.x + radius * Math.cos(angle), y: dragStartLocation.y - radius * Math.sin(angle)});
    angle += (2 * Math.PI) / sides;
}

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(coordinates[0].x, coordinates[0].y);
for (index = 1; index < sides; index++) {
    context.lineTo(coordinates[index].x, coordinates[index].y);
}

context.closePath();
context.stroke();
context.strokeStyle = strokeColor.value;

}
```

How can i save the coordinates for later use? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to do it OOP like. Don't know what your goal is, but I think there will be drawn much more shapes, which you maybe store in a array like object.

Also I think you are drawing them by having a dragStart and an dragEnd. That you want to create the Polygon objects by passing these values.

```
function Polygon(dragStartLocation, dragEndLocation, sides, angle) {

    { // init
        this.coordinates = [];
        this.radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((dragStartLocation.x - dragEndLocation.x), 2) + Math.pow((dragStartLocation.y - dragEndLocation.y), 2));
        this.strokeColor = {value: "#000000"}; // maybe also change color of the stroke

        for(index = 0; index < sides; index++) {
            this.coordinates.push({x: dragStartLocation.x + this.radius * Math.cos(angle), y: dragStartLocation.y - this.radius * Math.sin(angle)});
            angle += (2 * Math.PI) / sides;
        }
    }

    this.render = function() {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(this.coordinates[0].x, this.coordinates[0].y);
        for (index = 1; index < sides; index++) {
            context.lineTo(this.coordinates[index].x, this.coordinates[index].y);
        }

        context.closePath();
        context.strokeStyle = this.strokeColor.value;
        context.stroke();
    }
}
```

You can than create those objects when your drag stops. For example when your drag starts at `(100,100)` and ends at `(200, 200)`. The middlepoint of the Polygon will be `(100, 100)`.

```
new Polygon({x: 100, y: 100}, {x: 200, y: 200}, 8, 1);
```

Then you can store it in a variable or a array.

```
var list = new Array(
    new Polygon({x: 100, y: 100}, {x: 200, y: 200}, 8, 1), 
    new Polygon({x: 100, y: 100}, {x: 300, y: 300}, 12, 1)
);
```

After that you can easily draw them:

```
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].render();
}
```

This is how you can access the fields of the object.

```
list[i].coordinates;
```

But when you also want to translate, scale and rotate then you maybe want to store some other fields and maybe calculate the coordinates relative to a point. Then the transformations will be easier.

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you add a live demo please? jsfiddle maybe.

Comment: Hope it will work didn't use JSFiddle yet, in the code the mouse handling isn't the best, but I think you already handle it somehow ^^. [LiveDemo](https://jsfiddle.net/c0heuq3q/)